# Real time updates display like friend feed or twitter top tweets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, websub

I am using [PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub) to receive the recent updates on the feed. As soon as callback url receives the update, it should displayed in the web page like friend feed or twitter top tweets (content will move down as soon as new content arrives).

Is there any library to do this? Jquery?

Callback url receives the updates in atom xml format.

Thanks,
Mani

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a ready-made plugin for you but you can follow [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-twitter-like-load-more-widget/) tutorial to create one of your own.

Answer (score 1):

PubSubHubbub is a *server to server protocol*, which means you miss the connection between the server which receives the feed updates and the client (the browser in your case). There are obviously many ways to do it. One of them is to use a provider, like [Kwwika](http://kwwika.com/), [BeaconPush](http://beaconpush.com/) or [PusherApp](http://pusherapp.com/).

Another one is to implement this yourself. A small server which is able to deal with incoming PubSubHubbub Notifications, but also serve the some HTTP content, as well as update the content on the remote page. This can be done wit some Ajax, with long polling, or websockets. I would recommand [reading this article](http://blog.superfeedr.com/realtime-web-technologies/), which will give you a general overview.

Comment: Hi Julien, I read the article. Thanks. Can you post the link where I can see the real time update, a simple HTML + Javascript page (integrated into this Jekyll Blog!) ?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a nice JavaScript/Browser wrapper for this:

http://code.google.com/apis/feed/push/docs/index.html

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [socket-sub](https://github.com/julien51/socket-sub) if you have a Node.JS server.